# Web frontend to my Powershell scripts for helpdesk

Tags: sharepoint, iis, powershell, asp-classic, web-frontend

I'd like to have a web frontend to my powershell scripts for helpdesk.

These scripts would typically be user-creation scripts and scripts to restart a specific service on a specific server.

Where should I start? What would I need?

There is no problem for me to set up a IIS for this purpose if needed. We also have Sharepoint on a dedicated server.

Hoping for some startup-tips:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consider Powershell Web Access feature on Powershell V3.0
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831611.aspx

This is a robust solution, factoring in IIS, security and shell access.

Answer (score -2):

You can use *PowerShell Remoting*. You can open a PS session that would look like a local PS console to you but it would be running on the remote machine. You can type PS code to be executed remotely and launch a buch of ready-to-run *ps1* scripts for SP administration there too. Have a look at those links, for example:

http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_remote.htm, 
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/11/17/learn-how-to-manage-remote-powershell-sessions.aspx

--- Ferda

Comment: Thank you Ferdinand, but I already know about remoting. My question was about web frontend for my scripts:)